# Installing/Running Ethereum on Windows 10 (Bash)

Tags: installation

I am having this problem when starting geth in the bash terminal from windows 10. I have copied the entire startup initialization hoping it would help.

```
I0313 23:22:43.037940 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: unknown error [code -99]

I0313 23:22:43.073500 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata

I0313 23:22:44.322957 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata

I0313 23:22:44.324182 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7.3

I0313 23:22:44.337813 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata

I0313 23:22:44.794286 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1

I0313 23:22:44.910744 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}

I0313 23:22:45.203738 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #330190 [ab4b28d6…] TD=1585196455075519678

I0313 23:22:45.212893 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #330190 [ab4b28d6…] TD=1585196455075519678

I0313 23:22:45.214161 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #330190 [ab4b28d6…] TD=1585196455075519678

I0313 23:22:45.703194 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server

I0313 23:22:48.405451 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port udp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum discovery) using UPNP IGDv1-IP1

I0313 23:22:48.872306 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://27fcde294fae9fc39d2b0c214b4b0f978b1d2d7b2537e335d3e20ac2c5a2ed90729f24743776862868e79c6ff5b9c2121fbd6c2b8613fb5fda267bb271aca45d@192.168.1.17:30303

I0313 23:22:48.947764 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303

I0313 23:22:48.948806 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port tcp:30303 -> 30303
 (ethereum p2p) using UPNP IGDv1-IP1

I0313 23:22:49.665436 core/blockchain.go:589] Chain manager stopped

I0313 23:22:49.674374 eth/handler.go:230] Stopping ethereum protocol handler...

I0313 23:22:49.675264 eth/handler.go:251] Ethereum protocol handler stopped

I0313 23:22:49.766435 core/tx_pool.go:196] Transaction pool stopped

I0313 23:22:49.766864 eth/backend.go:519] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG 
OFF (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)

I0313 23:22:49.784234 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata

**Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /root/.ethereum/geth.ipc: setsockopt: invalid argument**
```

this is the error and I cannot get it past this. I have tried re isntalling. Do i need to download the entire blockchain without IPC first?

Today running just `geth console` with Firewall Active

`I0316 00:12:42.312686 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: unknown error [code -99]
I0316 00:12:42.313255 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:12:42.366329 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/Soran/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:12:42.367183 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7.3
I0316 00:12:42.367628 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:12:42.429047 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1
I0316 00:12:42.429811 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}
I0316 00:12:42.431679 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:12:42.431805 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:12:42.432469 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:12:42.433901 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0316 00:12:44.540307 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port udp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum discovery) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
I0316 00:12:44.576453 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://e7df34ed152a6b9e6c6e120f39ee6fbf754520e6740eb6bdf356046cfb9af123b39e982990526b5bdabc1a3f4fbc9c3f3b490751f9bde032d9056f6b09ff80bd@192.168.1.17:30303
I0316 00:12:44.585557 core/blockchain.go:589] Chain manager stopped
I0316 00:12:44.585702 eth/handler.go:230] Stopping ethereum protocol handler...
I0316 00:12:44.586616 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0316 00:12:44.587237 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port tcp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum p2p) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
I0316 00:12:44.587964 eth/handler.go:251] Ethereum protocol handler stopped
I0316 00:12:44.591975 core/tx_pool.go:196] Transaction pool stopped
I0316 00:12:44.592574 eth/backend.go:519] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: /home/usr/.ethash)
I0316 00:12:44.593466 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /home/usr/.ethereum/geth.ipc: setsockopt: invalid argument`

Firewall Inactive:

`I0316 00:17:08.502257 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: unknown error [code -99]
I0316 00:17:08.502883 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:17:08.556415 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:17:08.557228 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7.3
I0316 00:17:08.557686 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0316 00:17:08.619321 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1
I0316 00:17:08.620223 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}
I0316 00:17:08.622365 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:17:08.622492 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:17:08.623072 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0316 00:17:08.624508 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0316 00:17:10.730230 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port udp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum discovery) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
I0316 00:17:10.768005 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://e7df34ed152a6b9e6c6e120f39ee6fbf754520e6740eb6bdf356046cfb9af123b39e982990526b5bdabc1a3f4fbc9c3f3b490751f9bde032d9056f6b09ff80bd@192.168.1.17:30303
I0316 00:17:10.774215 core/blockchain.go:589] Chain manager stopped
I0316 00:17:10.774333 eth/handler.go:230] Stopping ethereum protocol handler...
I0316 00:17:10.781261 eth/handler.go:251] Ethereum protocol handler stopped
I0316 00:17:10.779717 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0316 00:17:10.779785 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port tcp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum p2p) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
I0316 00:17:10.782923 core/tx_pool.go:196] Transaction pool stopped
I0316 00:17:10.783890 eth/backend.go:519] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: /home/usr/.ethash)
I0316 00:17:10.788355 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/usr/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /home/usr/.ethereum/geth.ipc: setsockopt: invalid argument`

Comment: Hi, could you post the exact command you use to fire up your instance?

Comment: just ran `geth` to start it up

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any local firewall running on your machine? Can you start geth with `geth --console` and post its output?

Comment: I was poking around and found out my entire bash/sub system is corrupted. most likely from trying to install arch when it first came out. I am in the process of repairing it and will try re installing. Not what i was expecting though it does explain why `geth --console` wasnt working properly.

Comment: Ok, it would be good if you could share a result whenever you get it fixed :) Good luck!

Comment: Added both with and without firewall active (windows native firewall). doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: It starts synchronizing with the blocks with `geth -ipcdisable` however it does fail some synchronizations due to `block or receipt download cancelled(requested)` Im going to let it run overnight and see what happens

Comment: So to continue this debugging, the first error about `libusb` is because its not supported in windows 10 bash yet, so I wont be able to start the ledger until that is. as for the socket issue. I am still scratching my head